# Redirect with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a pointed domain keepyourlinks.com on my cpanel of piscolabis.info, so if you go to  piscolabis.info/keepyourlinks.com/ you acces it and i don't want that, i'm trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piscolabis.info/keepyourlinks.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work... :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piscolabis.info$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/keepyourlinks.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keepyourlinks.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But consider that i want piscolabis.info still reachble. will with this?